# Property 'item' does not exist on type 'P' - prop not available to use in higher order component despite it being in props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I'm fairly new to typescript and I'm trying to wrap my head around implementing HoCs with React in this context.

The example here is I'm trying to wrap a component with an HoC that will be checking whether the "item" passed into the "wrapped" component has in fact loaded yet. I can console.log(props) and see the item in there, but if I try to check anything about the item directly or output anything from the item I receive "Property 'item' does not exist on type 'P'"

Here's my very simple, where my "UserDetails" is being wrapped with "WithGetter"

```js
// UserDetails.tsx

import { User } from '../../../services/userService';
import { WithGetter } from '../../HOCs/WithGetter';

interface IUserDetails {
  item: User;
}

const UserDetails = ({ item }: IUserDetails) => {
  return (
    <div id='user-details'>
      <h2>Display User - {item?.id}</h2>
      <h3>{item?.name}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WithGetter(UserDetails);
```

```js
// WithGetter.tsx

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StandardLoader } from '../UtilityComponents/Loaders/Loaders';

type ExtraInfoType = {
  hasLoaded: boolean;
};

export function WithGetter<P>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P & ExtraInfoType>
) {
  const ComponentWithGetter = (props: P) => {
    const [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
    useEffect(() => {
      setHasLoaded(true);
    }, []);

    return (
      <div className='border-2 p-4'>
        {JSON.stringify(props.item)}
        {hasLoaded ? (
          <WrappedComponent {...props} hasLoaded={hasLoaded} />
        ) : (
          <StandardLoader />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };
  return ComponentWithGetter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing a generic constraint so TypeScript knows that the prop is guaranteed to be there:

```
export function WithGetter<P extends { item: unknown }>(
```

Comment: Boom, that did it. Thanks so much. I knew it was some simple syntactical thing. Much appreciated.